# Dynamics CRM 365 online data import stuck at "In Progress" reason

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, data-import, dynamics-crm-365

I have a Dynamics CRM 365 online. I'm trying to import data using the Data import wizard.

I've mapped all the fields correctly but the reason stays "In Progress". There are no error showing up.

I've read that restarting the asynchronous service may resolve this issue but how can I do it on an online version ?

Does somebody faced that issue ?

Comment: Check all other WF executing without error ? Also import with small chunk of data in your entity, or try basic entity like Account import to filter out other root causes.

Comment: The last time I ran into this issue, it was because the CSV file that I imported had millions of blank rows in it (the file was over 5MB even though I was trying to import just a few records).  I opened the CSV in a text editor, removed all of the extra rows, re-imported, and it finished very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The data import works on system jobs i.e. The Asynchronous process. This async processes stucks with status reason waiting for resources/ InProgress/ Waiting /Pausing due to different issues like-

1. Many jobs are in waiting status.
2. AsyncOperationBase table become full due to many succeeded/canceled jobs occupied space.
3. Asynchronous processes settings are not proper.
4. The asynchronous workflows are not configured properly.

Very first step is to restart the  Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous Processing Service. This might work in many cases.

You can find more solutions here-
[MS CRM Tech-MS DYNAMICS CRM 2016, DYNAMICS 365 SOLUTIONS](https://mscrm16tech.com/2018/04/14/asynchronous-processes-wrokflows-stuck-in-inprogress-waiting-status-in-ms-dynamic-crm/)